# Map overflowing content div, nevertheless most of map is grayed out? (jquery mobile)

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

So we have two problems here, both of which can be seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hR9x/4/ if you click the "testing" link at the bottom.

First of all, the content div which contains the map canvas is just overflowing right over the header bar. I was under the impression absolute positioning worked relative to the parent element, which is the content div, yet the map canvas is going right past that.

Also, you'll see that the map only appears in a small portion of the gray canvas, and refuses to expand...when dragged more into view, it resizes itself. Can anyone explain these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely positioning an element positions it relative to the page, except when it's parent is set to `position: absolute` or `position: relative`.

The content div is overflowing above the header because `map_canvas` is set to `position: absolute`. You need to give the div wrapping it `position: relative`, then it will no longer block the header bar.

That won't fix the secondary problem with your map's height though.